# Maximum number of solutions to $f(z)=az+b$ when $f''(z)$ has strictly positive real part $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, derivatives

> Suppose $f :\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function such that the real part of $f''(z)$ is strictly positive $\forall$ $z\in \mathbb{C}$. What is the maximum possible number of solutions to the equation $f (z)=az+b$, as $a$ and $b$ vary over all complex numbers?

The question is asking for the number of solutions to $f(z)=az+b$ given that $f''(z)$ has a strictly positive real part.

At first I take the derivative of $f(z)$, but it doesn't work. Consider for example 
$$f(z)=e^z-\left (\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\cdots \right )$$
which after cancelation give back $f(z)=z+1$.
But differentiating twice gives
$$e^z-1-z-\frac{z^2}{2!}-\frac{z^3}{3!}-\cdots$$
so in the end it gives $0$. However, $f''(z)$ should have a positive real part. I tried thinking but got no example that will give $f''(z)$ a positive real part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $f$ is an entire function and $\Re f''$ is positive then $f''$ is a  constant. So $f(z)$ has the form $\alpha+\beta z+\gamma z^{2}$.  Also $\Re f''(z)=2 \gamma >0$.

Comment: if a $f$ is entire then its $f'$ is also entire $\implies$ $f''$ is entire ?

Comment: Yes, all derivatives of $f$ exist and they are also entire functions. @TheStudent

Comment: The question does not say that $f''$ is real valued, but that the real part of $f''$ is strictly positive. The conclusion remains the same, however.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much. I read the assumption wrongly as $f''$ itself being positive.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i think $\gamma$ should >0

Comment: So you basically mean that there should be no solution such as $f(z)=az+b$, right?

Comment: @Brozovic $az+b$ is not a solution because the second derivative is $0$ in this case.

Comment: I think solution of $f(z)=az+b$ is    $cz^2+dz+e=az+b$ which will be a quadratic in $z$ so total $2$ solution. Am i right @KaviRamaMurthy ?

Comment: @honeykumar Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you @KaviRamaMurthy, for your response.